# Robust Audio Conversion Utility for Windows platform

Tags: conversion, windows, batch-processing

Out of curiosity, does anybody know of and/or could recommend a good batch conversion utility that's in the same vain as Barbabatch but for the Windows environment.  I'm seeking something just as robust, even if it costs to purchase the program.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dBPowerAmp (http://www.dbpoweramp.com/)
It's the one and only, and not very expensive either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Does this one also allow batch bit dept and freq response conversions as well (the site notes that DSP functions are available, but it didn't elaborate)? 

Comment: Yup, it does bit depth 8-32 bit and sample rates from 8KHz (why??) all the way up to 192KHz, and will convert mono - 8 channels deep as well.

You can also batch-apply any directX or VST plugin you might have, plus some built-in ones like EQ, normalize, remove silence, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Foobar2000 + all nesessary plugins and codecs. Its free, higly customizable, but needs advanced user's skills. But it worth it!

Answer (score 1):

Sound Forge has a really nice batch converter. Eq, vsts, reverse, fades.. etc. Check the trial.

Also, Reaper has one, haven't used it enough beyond file conversion.